# Data binding не обновляет textview MVVM Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-data-binding

Изучаю MVVM, пишу счетчик нажатий на кнопку. Есть класс, в котором есть только одно значение Int. Этот класс передается в viewmodel и из viewmodel берется значение в textview. При первом включении отображается корректно, значение устанавливаемое строкой `val data = percent(0)`, нажатия обрабатываются (по логам переменная меняет значение), но значение в textview не обновляется. Я полагаю, проблема в live data или в отсутствии оповещения об изменении данных. Я пытался это сделать, но ни к чему это не привело. Что необходимо сделать?

xml:

```
<layout ...>

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.recyclingstarter.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />
    </data
    <ConstraintLayout ...>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:text="@{String.valueOf(vm.data.value)}"/>
        <Button
            android:onClick="@{() -> vm.increase()}"
            .../>

...
```

Percent.kt:

```
data class percent(var value: Int)
```

MainViewModel.kt:

```
public class MainViewModel(var data: precent) : ViewModel() {
fun increase(){
    data.value++
    Log.d("viewmodelcheck", data.value.toString())
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
lateinit var binding : ActivityMainBinding
lateinit var ViewModel : MainViewModel

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main)
    val data = percent(0) // При изменении значения, изначальный текст будет показан
    ViewModel = MainViewModel(data)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    binding.vm = ViewModel
    ...
```

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}
...
    dataBinding {
        enabled true
    }
...
    kapt 'com.android.databinding:compiler:4.1.1'
```

Comment: Попробуйте в конце increase() вызвать notifyChange()

Comment: Не получилось( 
Я решил иначе, ответ ниже

Answer (score 0):

Решением оказалось необходимость в создании livedata во viewmodel:

```
public class MainViewModel(var data: precent) : ViewModel() {
    val num: MutableLiveData<Int> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<Int>().apply { value = data.value } // задаем входное значение
    }
    fun increase(){
        num.value = num.value!!.toInt() + 1
        Log.d("viewmodelcheck", num.value.toString())
    }
}
```